# Can we have a variable explorer in VScode like in Spyder?

Tags: variables, visual-studio-code, settings, spyder, explorer

I'm looking for a extension or a settings in VScode to see a "variable explorer" like in Spyder (as you can see in the picture) when we can see every objects (and not only the variable !) and information about them directly in a screen. I didn't find any extensions.

I know we can "open a notebook and see the variables" with Jupyter but it's really far from the features that spyder offers.

Can you help me ?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right-click "*Run Current File in Python Interactive Window*" in the script, and select "*Show variables active in jupyter kernel*"