# Virtualenv cannot find newly installed Python version

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.10

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to start a project using Python 3.10. I used an install guide for Python 3.10 ([this one](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python-on-ubuntu-linux-system/)), installed it using the deadsnakes PPA, and that was fine:

```bash
$ python3.10
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun 11 2022, 16:53:24) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I even switched my default python to 3.10 for good measure, using [this](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-switch-python-version-in-ubuntu-debian/), and that also works.

```bash
$ python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun 11 2022, 16:53:24) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Yet I cannot build a virtual environment:

```bash
$ virtualenv myenv -p python3.10         
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.10'
```

And if I try to rely on the default, it gives me python3.8. I had been using python3.8 before alright, but I don't know where that setting is coming from. Pyenv is installed, I don't know if that's interfering nor not.

```bash
$ virtualenv myenv                                                                                                
created virtual environment CPython3.8.10.final.0-64 in 110ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/jokea/FlorA/fl-scraper/myenv, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/jokea/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
```

I just want to make a virtualenv with Python3.10. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was running into the same issue with a fresh python3.7 install. I managed to fix it by installing `distutils`.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That was it. Hats off to you good sir.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to enter a full path to your python3.10 when creating virtualenv, ex:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.10 venv
```

Comment: I tried that, it gives me this weird error:
`RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.10 with code 1 err: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py:16: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential...`

Comment: Yes, I get same error. Is there any updates?